# Fast queue on top of Chronicle Map?

Tags: akka-persistence, chronicle, chronicle-map

We are implementing [storage plugin](https://github.com/carrot-garden/akka-persistence-chronicle) for [akka-persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html)
That means 2 providers, for:

1. queue-like [Journal plugin API](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html#Journal_plugin_API)
2. map-like [Snapshot store plugin API](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html#Snapshot_store_plugin_API)

Since only [Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) supports multi-node symmetric replication,
we eliminate [Chronicle Queue](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue) from consideration.

Question: what is the best way to create fast queue on top of the map? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with using chronicle-queue for journal, chronicle-map for snapshot,
and ditching chronicle networking layer in favor of native akka cluster replication.